# Ubuntu 18.04 internet connection not working (using VMWare Fusion)

Tags: networking, 18.04, vmware, vmware-fusion

Not sure what happened. Yesterday everything worked, today I booted up my VMware and it seems Ubuntu doesn't have an internet connection at all.

Tried all the different options (besides NAT that I normally use) like Bridged and Host-Only but it didn't help. Tried restarting my network via terminal etc. Under Ubuntu's internet settings it just shows that no Wi-Fi adapter is found.

Not sure what happened overnight, maybe some update that got installed? I did accidentally turn off the host computer before I could correctly shut down Ubuntu's VMware session but I doubt that did anything. Windows 7 that is also running on VMware on the other hand works perfectly.

How to proceed? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Followed this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1400504 and got it working :)

Comment: Note this issue might be happened when a guest ubuntu getting resume from suspended. But I'm not sure how to fundamentally fix it from vmware.

Comment: Had the same problem with Ubuntu 20 and I noticed that this occurs after you switch Wi-Fi networks. The solution in this case is a simple restart of Ubuntu and the VM.

Answer (score 30):

Got it working by browsing through multiple threads.

*EDIT : Please check if your network is in bridged mode or not if you are using VMWare/ VirtualBox before following the steps below. Enabling bridge mode and restarting guest OS can resolve the issue.*

First check if your network is disabled by using the following cmd  in terminal:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

If it shows disabled after the name of your adapter ( note down the logical name for later use)

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: ens33
```

All we need to do is enable the adapter, so lets get started.

open up your interfaces file by using the following cmd:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

My file had the following data written:

```
auto lo
iface lo loopback
```

But the logical name of my NIC was ens33 ( not lo), so i changed it to read the following and saved the file.

```
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet dhcp
```

Now time to restart the networking service .

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

check if network is back up, it shouldn't have that disabled tag anymore.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Enjoy your internet :)

Comment: This was very helpful. Solved my exact problem.

Comment: The file names/content have changed now in 18.04.3- it seems to be  have changed its /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml - the content that I have is  `network:
    ethernets:
        ens33:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2`   so what do we do next

Comment: I have a virtual machine with 18.04.3 LTS and the above answer still holds true. Do you mind sharing the path of interfaces file ?

Comment: My host os is ubuntu 18.04 and guest os is ubuntu 18.04. I did this and it does not work. then in `vmware -> virtual machine settings` I changed to `bridge mode` and restarted the networking service in guest os (`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`). And it works.

Comment: netplan users use `sudo netplan apply` after changing the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks a lot.....You are a life saver....I will share this answer in stackoverflow as well.
Although this change was required ===> 
 vmware -> virtual machine settings ==> changed to bridge mode

Comment: Great answer, this has fixed multiple VMs for me where I have no clue why the networking isn't going.