# Ubuntu 20.04.3 VMWare Fusion No Internet Connection Issue

Tags: networking, internet, vmware-fusion

Everything works fine except I can't get the internet to work. The internet has never been able to work. I tried several methods for other versions of Ubuntu on VMWare fusion, but none of them have worked.

I tried [Ubuntu 18.04 internet connection not working (using VMWare Fusion)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073031/ubuntu-18-04-internet-connection-not-working-using-vmware-fusion), but it didn't work.

My network adaptor is on NAT and is using internet sharing with my Mac, but the Ubuntu VM wasn't able to get the connection. In the settings of the Ubuntu VM, when I searched for Wi-Fi, it says that it couldn't find any Wi-Fi adapters.

I used the command `sudo lshw -C network` and it says that my network is disabled.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: ens33
       version: 01
```

It would be very much appreciated if someone could tell me what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network is currently disabled. There are a couple different reasons for this. Try running the following:

```
sudo ifconfig ens33 up
```

if you don't have access to `ifconfig` for whatever reason, try:

```
sudo ip link set ens33 up
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks!